# Django client side validation on decimal field limit

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, django-models

I wanted to limit django model decimal field to 4 places in client side itself meaning field should not allow user to enter more than 4 digits.

I tried below code but its get validate only after save but i need to limit while user entering digits.

```
unit_price = models.DecimalField(db_column='UNIT_PRICE', max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a widget in your Form definition?

```
unit_price = forms.DecimalField(
    widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': '0.01', 'min': '0.00', 'max': '99.99' }))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, adding js to the form works as I accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a little javascript to restrict the user from entering more than 4 digits use the below snippet in forms and javascript files

**forms**

```
unit_price = forms.DecimalField(
    widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'step': '0.01', 'min': '0.00', 'max': '99.99', onkeypress: 'return isValid(event)'}))
```

**javascript**

```
function isValid(event) {
  var val = document.getElementById('test').value;
  val = val.split('.').join('');
  event = (event) ? event : window.event;
  var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
  if (val.length < 4 || charCode == 8 || charCode == 37 || charCode == 39 || charCode == 46){
     return true;
  }
  else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

By this way, the user input can be restricted to 4 places on keypress too

Comment: 'plus one',  works great, thanks lot for the quick solution @gowtham

Comment: but after entering 4 digits, I am not able to delete those digits.

Comment: @Sohan I have corrected the answer now. You were not able to delete because else part of the condition will be executed after 4 digits are entered so have checked for keycode

Comment: thanks for the editing. It worked fine for normal admin form, but when I tried same thing in admin tabularinline, JS code is not reflecting, I think I am not abled to pass proper "getElementById" because its keep changing for every line right? How can I achieve same in this case?